# Computing $\int_0^{\ln2}\sqrt{4e^{2x}+\frac12+\frac{1}{64}e^{-2x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve $$\int_0^{\ln2}\sqrt{4e^{2x}+\frac12+\frac{1}{64}e^{-2x}}dx$$ This looks like a problem where I can let $u=e^{2x}, u^{-1}=e^{-2x}$ and treat the function inside the root as a quadratic. I was able to do this, however, I was not able to factor it such that I could get a product of two binomials.

I tried u-substitution but it ended up being a mess that required integration by parts.

Can someone help show the simplest solution step by step?

Answer (score 2):

I just follow through your substitution

$$\int_1^4\sqrt{4u^2 + \frac{u}{2} + \frac{1}{64}}du$$

$$\int_1^4\sqrt{4(u^2 + \frac{u}{8} + \frac{1}{256}})du$$

$$\int_1^42\sqrt{(u^2 + 2.\frac{1}{16}.u + (\frac{1}{16})^2}du$$

$$\int_1^42|u+\frac{1}{16}|du$$

Comment: +1, the modulus is not required... because $e^{x} \ge 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$

Comment: True, just for completeness

Comment: I'm still confused. I don't know how you factored that in the first line. Could you show more work please

Answer (score 1):

Notice the coefficients $4$ and $\frac{1}{64}$ don't match up. So factor a constant out:

$$ \sqrt{4e^{2x}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{64}e^{-2x}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{16e^{2x}+2+\frac{1}{16}e^{-2x}} $$

Now the radicand is a perfect square...